# Cakephp htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp

I am new with cakephp and i have some dificulties...

What I am trying to make is to load the index of the site with a url like:

http://mydomain/aboutus

If I not use cake i would as folowing:

RewriteRule ^aboutus$ index.php [L,QSA]

but how to do with cake? :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

These 'redirections' are handled by CakePHP.
You should use [Routes](http://book.cakephp.org/#!/view/1541/Routes) in order to program 'redirecting'.
Keep in mind the following default line at /app/config/routes.php
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));

You probably want something like
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'aboutus'));

Answer (score 0):

Check out following section in CakePHP's book: [Apache and mod_rewrite (and .htaccess)](http://book.cakephp.org/view/917/Apache-and-mod_rewrite-and-htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

In the router.php

Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'YOURCONTOLLERNAME', 'action' => 'WHERE U WANT TO REDIRECT'));

Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'));

i hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Change routes.php  where you want to redirect :

Router::connect('/cruize',array('controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'cruizer','cruize' =>true));

OR

you can change .htaccess file according you.

RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
    php_value post_max_size 500M
    php_value upload_max_filesize 500M
    php_value memory_limit 10024M
    php_value max_execution_time 15000
    php_value max_input_time 1500